# I cant create a minecraft server

Tags: java, jar, server, minecraft

I've been trying to create a Minecraft server for 1.13, it will download but when I try to open server.jar using Java(TM) Platform SE binary it opens for less then a second and it gives me an error message that I cant read because it closes way to fast to even read the first word, after trying to run it once if you try again it wont give any error messages but just open and close in less then a second, anyone know what I can do?

Comment: use a command prompt and start it there.

Comment: @Luigiproo Whenever you ask questions on StackOverflow, it's usually about coding.  Your question is more about using software.  My suggestion is to put this on SuperUser.  My bet is you'll get better answers.  I don't know if Arqade will have more or if ServerFault will either, but try SuperUser.  The negative votes simply mean your question isn't related to StackOverflow (in my opinion).  Don't be discouraged.  Start at SuperUser.  f1sh made a great suggestion.  Open the Command Prompt and run it from there.  The Window won't close and you can see the error. I voted to close for this reason.

Comment: alright I will try that thank you

Comment: well i tried to start it from command prompt and it says that it cant find server.jar

Comment: You have to change the command prompt to work in the same directory as the jar file is located. If you're in windows explorer, navigate to the folder where the jar file is located and click on the folder bar, copy it. Then in command prompt, type cd and then left click to paste the folder path. Hit enter, then try to run server.jar again.

Answer (score 2):

I did this once over my home network for my kids and I used the information I found in this link:

https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server

It goes into quite a bit of detail but if I remember correctly, as long as you have the server jar file, an up-to-date JRE it's as simple as clicking a batch file to run a server locally.

The only gotcha I can remember was that when you run the server for the first time a document is generated which you'll need to edit to say you agree to the EULA before the server will start up.

Comment: Just FYI: questions that are off-topic should not be answered.